# Beamer error when using an optional argument of the \cite command

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}[\cite[p. 42]{Author}]
    Nice example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

  \bibitem{Author}
    Author,
    Title,
    Publisher,
    2016.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the above file I got the error

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
Runaway argument?
p. 42)\fi \end {beamercolorbox}{\parskip 0pt
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

If I removed `[p. 42]` from the `\cite` command, the error disappears.

How can I use the optional argument of the `\cite` command in the optional argument of the `example` environment?

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
```

Comment: Do you cite this work more than once? Otherwise you could do something like `\bibitem[1, p.42]{Author}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}[{\cite[p. 42]{Author}}]% added {...}
    Nice example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{Author}
    Author,
    Title,
    Publisher,
    2016.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

nested `[ ... ]` in (any) options is not allowed. It had to be inside curly braces, i.e. as  `{[...]}`

[image]